# How to create urls for .NET Core application in Apache virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, apache, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server, mod-proxy-html

ASP.NET Core application is created using Visual Studion 2019  ASP.NET Core Application project template.

Its _layout.cshtml contains css file paths relative to application root directory:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - WebApplication1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
```

This application is running in Debian Linux 10 with apache in nettest virtual directory using instructions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache

Apache mod_proxy and header modules are user to forward https requests to kestrel server. Apache conf file:

```
<Location "/nettest">
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass  http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse  http://127.0.0.1:5000/
</location>
```

Application does not find css files. Browser view source shows that absolute paths are rendered in html code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Home Page - WebApplication1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
</head>
```

how to force to render proper URLs, eq. relative from current folder like

> lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

or absolute from application virtual directory:

> /nettest/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

** Update **

After changing order css files are found. However Privacy link in sample applicatino tempate is still not working.

ASP.NET template contains:

```
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

In browser in appears as

```
           <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/nettest">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/nettest/Home/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Home link works but Privacy link throws 404 error.

In template HomeController  is is defined:

```
public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

It works when application is running under Visual Studio. How to make privary link to work when application is running in Apache virtual directory ?

Configure method:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-2.2
        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        app.UseAuthentication();


        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        // origoli:            app.UseStaticFiles();

        //        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593999/how-to-host-a-asp-net-core-application-under-a-sub-folder

        // https://forums.asp.net/post/6327484.aspx
        //  because the middleware
        //app.UsePathBase("/nettest");
        //  strips the /nettest from the pipeline, the static file handler middleware needs to come first:
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            RequestPath = new PathString("/nettest")
        });
        app.UsePathBase("/nettest");
        // in asp.net core, you control the order of middleware and must get it correct.

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue might be with the order you defined UseStaticFiles and UseAuthentication. Move UseStaticFiles above UseAuthentication.
A better approach is to use Apache itself to render the static files.

Comment: After changing order css fields are found but Privacy controller call still thros 404 error. I updated question

Comment: Remove slash after ProxyPass  and ProxyPassReverse.

Comment: `ProxyPass  http://127.0.0.1:5000/nettest`   (without slash) worked. Thank you.